# Will I have problem getting student visa after being refused once?

Tags: visas, study, visa-refusals

I am from Bangladesh and I applied for a student Visa for Masters study(MSc) at the German embassy. But since I was already enrolled in a MBA here in my home country, my visa was rejected. The official reason was "Since your bachelors you have enrolled in a masters study but did not finish. With this there is strong doubt about your higher study intentions". They also put a stamp in my passport which says 'D visa applied'.

My question is **will this rejection haunt me in future if I apply for visa in other Schengen countries** such as Finland, Norway etc ? Or in US & Canada ?

Is there any consequence of this refusal and if there is how to mitigate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question often arises after a refusal, and the standard response to your question when it comes from 'official' sources is '...no, each  application is considered independently and decided solely upon its merit...'.

In more practical terms, it will inevitably be taken into account and thus may affect the outcome of future applications OF THE SAME TYPE.  For applications of a different type, a visitor visa or spouse visa for example, their grounds may be irrelevant.  Those types of visas do not require serious intent to pursue a course of study and hence your credibility cannot be assailed.

Based upon what you wrote, the German official, however captious it may seem, identified a serious weakness in your application and refused you on credibility.  It means that you did not see this opportunity for them to refuse and fortify your application with an explanation along the lines of  '...I will not complete the MBA program in Bangladesh because...' possibly including a recommendation from your faculty adviser that you pursue a degree in Germany.

You can also increase the chances of success by a history of performance.  That sort of thing is obtained by travelling to lots of countries that require visas. You can also point to significant changes in circumstances in the intervening time since your refusal.  These two things work wonderfully in overcoming the stigma of a visa refusal.

So the answer to your question:  'will it haunt me?' is yes, for applications as a student the refusal is relevant.  And the corollary, 'will I be automatically refused?' is no.  And the related question, 'does a refusal spill over to other types of applications?', generally no.

Another related question is '...can I get a new passport without a stamp in it and then not declare a prior refusal?...'  No, it's a naive tactic that will blossom into a major credibility hit.

The greatest chance for future success is to have your application managed by a licensed practitioner in Germany or in the country where you are applying.  Avoid practitioners in Bangladesh generally unless they have documented correspondence status with a regulated EU law firm.

Comment: `can I get a new passport without a stamp in it and then not declare a prior refusal`. That will be fraud, and guarantee you a visa from the country next to impossible. Or maybe locked out of applying again for maybe some time.

Comment: If i finish my degree, that would constitute significant changes right? I could reapply then ?

Comment: @stackex00 - `constitute significant changes right` No, why do you think so ? You will still be applying for a student visa only. You can reapply now also if you want to, but you will find it hard to convince.

Comment: What plausible step can I take then? I want to apply for another schengen country next year.

Comment: @DumbCoder, it's a very poor strategy indeed.  But the number of people who try it is astonishing, hence worth a mention.

Comment: @stackex00, please read the last paragraph.  That's your plausible step.

Comment: Ok then, I will find a lawyer. Thank you all for your responses.